# Javac "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, compilation, command-line-interface, javac

I've the root directory like this :

```
├── classes
└── src
    └── vehicles
        ├── Bicycle.java
        └── BicycleMain.java
```

Bicycle.java

```
package vehicles;

public class Bicycle {

  public int cadence;
  public int gear;
  public int speed;

  public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
    gear = startGear;
    cadence = startCadence;
    speed = startSpeed;
  }

  public void setCadence(int newValue) {
      cadence = newValue;
  }
  public void setGear(int newValue) {
    gear = newValue;
  }
  public void setSpeed(int newValue) {
    speed = newValue;
  }
  public int getGear() {
    return gear;
  }
  public int getCadence() {
    return cadence;
  }
  public int getSpeed() {
    return speed;
  }
  public void applyBrake(int decrement) {
    speed -= decrement;
  }
  public void speedUp(int increment) {
    speed += increment;
  }
```

BicycleMain.java

```
package vehicles; import vehicles.*;

public class BicycleMain {
        public static void main (String args[]){
        Bicycle Bike = new Bicycle(10, 20, 1);
        System.out.println("We have a new bicycle with speed = " +Bike.getSpeed()+", cadence = "+Bike.getCadence()+", gear = "+Bike.getGear());
        } }
```

I compiled the Bicycle.java and successful, but not for BicycleMain.java :

```
symbol  : class Bicycle
location: class vehicles.BicycleMain
    Bicycle Bike = new Bicycle(10, 20, 1);
    ^
src/vehicles/BicycleMain.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Bicycle
location: class vehicles.BicycleMain
    Bicycle Bike = new Bicycle(10, 20, 1);
                       ^
2 errors
```

I try to run these files with Netbeans and IT WORKS! but why it doesn't work when I compile in CLI?

Comment: Why have you posted the source for your classes? How is it relevant to your question? Please read [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org)

Comment: What classpath have you used for the compilation?

Comment: Are you compiling from `src` ?

Comment: I try to compile in many path before, except "src". I just tried to delete import command then compile from "src", and it works! well thanks..

Comment: @Bohemian - I'm sure glad he posted them, at least that makes it "Self Contained, Compilable, Example" - what would you have done? Just posted "src/vehicles/BicycleMain.java:6: cannot find symbol
"?

Comment: @sdaau ideally, post the smallest amount of code that causes the error, and the error message, so others can simply copy-paste into their IDE and reproduce the problem themselves.

Comment: Tink solved that one for reproducal ones recently and provides links. Sounds like.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First, To compile the java source file using `javac` you need to specify the files to compile explicitly.

Example:

```
javac PathToSourceFile/FileName.java
```

you need not provide the `path` if the source file is in the current working directory.

Second, whenever java encounters `import abc.xyz.ClassName;` it tries to resolve `abc/xyz/ClassName` with respect to the `classpath` or current working directory.

So if you are inside the vehicles folder and compile your code, it wont compile because it will look for folder vehicles inside folder vehicles (which doesn't exist!).

but, you can do this when inside the vehicles folder

```
javac -cp ../ BicycleMain.java
```

and it should compile, because classpath will be set to the directory(`../`) containing vehicles. which will resolve your `Bicycle` class.

and then use

`java -cp ../ vehicles/BicycleMain` to run.

Comment: Alternatively, go into your `src` directory (the one containing the `vehicles` directory), compile using `javac vehicles/BicycleMain.java`, and run using `java vehicles.BicycleMain`.

Answer (score 11):

Try deleting the line `import vehicles.*;` from `BicycleMain.java` and them compiling with javac in command line.

By the way it happens because while you are compiling in javac you are in the folder `vehicles` and you write a statement `import vehicles.*;` in `BicycleMain.java` which means to the compiler there is another folder `vehicles` within the `vehicles` folder which is not the case here

Comment: this my fault to compile in incorrect folder, I deleted the import command and try to compile in "src", it works! thanks...

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem, compiling from "src".

Something like this: `javac ./my_folder/my_file.java`

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions here but eventually I found that the problem for me was I was using different versions of the JDK and JRE.

Check JRE version:

```
java -version
```

Check JDK version:

```
javac -version
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the package line from beginning and it'll work 100%.

Go to the folder in which files are stored via terminal and 
type **javac *.java**

There will be no need to import classes too.

Comment: Only option that worked for me. By the way, I'm using Windows 7.