# Cannot Find Symbol. Computer Specific

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I can't seem to run these files without getting a cannot symbol error.

I run the exact same code on another computer and it works. I'm guessing its a problem with my path? But both java and javac work in cmd.

Thanks so much tell me if you have any questions.

Here is my two files I cant connect (EXACT same on both computers, including fileName).

Both files are in the **same folder** and **javac** is installed on both the computers.

Test.java file

```
public class Test {
  public Test(){
    System.out.println("it's working");
  }
 }
```

TestRun.java file

```
public class TestRun {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}
}
```

Commands:

```
$ javac Test.java
$ javac TestRun.java
$ java TestRun
```

Output:

```
it's working
```

But the same is not working in another computer

Comment: In machine where it is not working did you try javac on both java source first ?

Comment: In your another PC where it is not working, have you added class to classpath?

Comment: I tried both of the above and neither worked.... javac worked on the working machine but not the broken one. I added the classpath which was a good idea. But still no cigar. Other thoughts? I'm really stuck.

Comment: Is javac even installed on the second computer?

Comment: Are both .class files in the same folder on both computers? Do they have any "package xxxxx;" heading?

Comment: What is the location in the error?? see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537668/javac-cannot-find-symbol  Use  **javac PathToSourceFile/Test.java** and **javac PathToSourceFile/TestRun.java**

Comment: *How* is it not working? Is there any sort of error message?

Comment: use **javac -sourcepath src -d classes PathToSourceFile/Test.java** and **javac -sourcepath src -d classes PathToSourceFile/TestRun.java**... maybe this will work... otherwise at least display your error message here.. so we can understand

Comment: Sorry, but do you seriously need to run Java from the command line?  Join the 21st century and start using eclipse or NetBeans.  Unless you are ssh'ing into a machine or something and you absolutely have to run through the command line.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! As instructed above it was a problem with my path. A missing ';'. Thanks again everyone.