# Compiling source code makes .jar significantly smaller?

Tags: java, eclipse

///WARNING- I DO NOT KNOW ANY LANGUAGES/HAVE NO USED ECLIPSE BEFORE\\

I'm currently trying to get a .jar file compiled in Java8 to compile in Java7, but seem to be having trouble, I have the source code intact so that is not the problem. It compiles fine, but the finished .jar is smaller than the original by a large margin. I believe the problem lies in my inexperience with Eclipse meaning I problably did something wrong.

Source Folder Structure
src\com\darkblade12\enchantplus...java files

Contents Of Each Folder

[image]

[image]

Comment: [darkblade12 contents][3]
        

[enchantplus contents][4]
        

[Eclipse Setup][5]
         
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VcLn4.png
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/E8xz5.png
  [5]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xfYeV.png

Answer (score 0):

- If you have some doubts about eclipse being behind the problem, try to compile it directly using the Command line Interface with the target version version of java by using javac.
  Example for Windows:

  ```
  set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.7.0_21
  javac com/darkblade12/enchantplus/*.java
  jar cvf program.jar -C com/darkblade12/enchantplus
  ```

  Then compare your jar generated by eclipse and this generated directly from the command line.
- Another way to verify is to open the jar file with and archive manager like 7-zip and verify its content.

Comment: Gives me an error when trying to do so... 100 errors total... many cannot find symbols.

Comment: Perhaps `javac -cp ../../.. com/darkblade12/enchantplus/*.java` would work. Please check this link for a similar question: [cannot find symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537668/javac-cannot-find-symbol). Otherwise open your two jar generated by eclipse by 7-zip and verify its content as told before. I hope that can help.